# Find Bounds on Polynomial Extrema

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods

Given a real polynomial $p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n c_i x^i $ of degree $n$ on the interval [-1,1]. I would like to find bounds $a$ and $b$ such that

$$
a < p(x) < b \textrm{ for } x \in [-1,1] 
$$

I would like to find the bounds without determining the actual extrema of $p(x)$ (finding the zeros of $p'(x)$ and so on) as $n$ is large between $10^6$ and $10^7$. I am specifically interested in numerical methods where I can trade-off bound accuracy and computational complexity. For example, a simple bound is given by $\sum_{i=0}^n |c_i| $. Optionally, $p(x)$ is given in terms of Chebychev polynomials.

Comment: You could consider interval arithmetic, combined with the Horner scheme for polynomial evaluation. Repeated use with refined subdivisions would give a measure of the achieved quality.

Comment: @LutzL Would you add a few more words about your proposal? I can apply Horner's method to compute $p$ and $p'$, so by sampling I can get a lower bound for $b$ and an upper bound for $a$ as well as suggestions as to where better approximations can be found. Is this your intention?

Comment: Would you add a few words or a link about the application which gave rise to this problem. Moreover, how large is $n$? I collect examples for use in my classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing coefficients for a Chebyshev or Bernstein basis has cost $O(n^2)$, these give reasonable enclosures for the range of function values.

I interpret your question as the task to find non-trivial bounds on the range in complexity $O(n)$. One possibility is to find the following characteristics of the coefficient sequence
\begin{align}
C_{e,p}&=\sum_{m:c_{2m}>0} c_{2m}\tag{even index, positive coefficient}\\
C_{e,n}&=-\sum_{m:c_{2m}<0}c_{2m}\tag{even index, negative coefficient}\\
C_{o,p}&=\sum_{m:c_{2m+1}>0} c_{2m+1}\tag{odd index, positive coefficient}\\
C_{o,n}&=-\sum_{m:c_{2m+1}<0} c_{2m+1}\tag{odd index, negative coefficient}\\
\end{align}
Then we know that the range over $[0,1]$ is contained in $[-C_{e,n}-C_{o,n},C_{e,p}+C_{o,p}]$, and over $[-1,0]$ in $[-C_{e,n}-C_{o,p}, C_{e,p}+C_{o,n}]$. A bound on the values over $[-1,1]$ is thus
$$
|p(x)|\le M=\max\{C_{e,n}+C_{o,n},\,C_{e,p}+C_{o,p},\,C_{e,n}+C_{o,p},\, C_{e,p}+C_{o,n}\},
$$
or as separate upper and lower bounds
$$
-C_{e,n}-\max(C_{o,n},\,C_{o,p})\le p(x)\le C_{e,p}+\max(C_{o,n},C_{o,p}).
$$
Essentially this is the result of a direct application of an interval evaluation for the interval $[-1,1]$ to the monomial representation of the polynomial. Using the Horner scheme for the evaluation not only reduces the effort but might also result in tighter bounds. Another way for a refinement is to use a fixed sub-division of the interval and combination of the results of the interval evaluations for every subinterval.

Comment: Are you referring by $c_{2m}$ to Chebyshev coefficients?

Comment: No, it was written with the monomial coefficients in mind, just as formulated in the question. The Chebyshev functions $\cos(n\arccos(x))$ oscillate everywhere, their range is $[-1,1]$ on both $[-1,0]$ and $[0,1]$ except for $n=0,1$. The subdivision in these 4 cases does not work in this case.

Comment: Sorry, now I got it. Is this true for $c_i = 1$ for all $i$?

Comment: If all coefficients are positive then the simple bound that you cited is actually the function value at $x=1$. But you are right, there is something wrong in my bound, one needs to sum over all these coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem might be useful. As would using Asymptotics of $x^n$ as that would help determine what it roughly does.

Comment: I'm afraid that the squeezing theorem does not tell how to find actually the bounds.

Comment: no inexact method, will find the bounds exactly.